# Collegescorecard - individual-level anonymized data

Tags: data-request, releasing-data, collegescorecard

Where does the individual-level anonymized data for the [collegescorecard](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/) live? For obvious reasons, this would be more valuable to researchers than the summary data.

I don't see any access to it from the [documentation](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/documentation/)

Answer (score 1):

College Scorecard data are only available at the institution-level.  Many of the data elements are derived from IPEDS data reported to the Department by institutions at the institution-level, see http://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/. Most of the  other data elements are derived from the National Student Loan Data System (NSLDS), the Department's central database for student aid. Individual schools and individual students have access to their own individual-level data through NSLDS, see https://www.nsldsfap.ed.gov/nslds_FAP/ and https://www.nslds.ed.gov/nslds/nslds_SA/ .

Comment: Thanks Brian! I see that the data is currently only available at the institution level. However, the individual data must obviously exist. Why isn't it available with the institution data? And/or how can it be made available?

Comment: Alex, appreciate your interest, but at this time the Department does not have a system in place for nongovernment researchers to access student-level NSLDS data

Comment: Brian, [why not](https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/memoranda/2013/m-13-13.pdf)? The data would be valuable. And obviously it could be anonymized to ensure privacy.

Comment: We appreciate your interest, and will consider it moving forward. However, at this time, we are not able to provide such data to external parties